# Как смотреть в консоли зависшие php-скрипты

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache, nginx

Запросы пользователей из браузера поступают на сервер, проходят через ngix, затем apache запускает php-скрипты.

Иногда случается так, что некоторые php-скрипты плохо оптимизированы и висят в памяти и кушают ресурсы.

Вопрос: как посмотреть php-скрипты, которые работают в текущий момент (запущенные apache-м)?

Comment: а как вы узнали, что они "зависли", висят в памяти и кушают ресурсы? у вас лимит по времени для пхп отключен?

Comment: включен. Тем не менее лимит не действует при определенных операциях. Например, sleep(300) и будет скрипт висеть 5 минут и занимать память и т.д. Пока sleep-пауза, счетчик для set_time_limit  или max_execution_time не увеличивается. Но вопрос топика не про это.